# How to open a particular Eclipse wizard or dialog from the command line?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I want to open the Install Connectors dialog from the command line instead via Eclipse | Preferences | Team | SVN (the button to open this wizard is usually missing from the Preferences UI due to some bug in the Subversive plug-in).

So how do I ...

- open Eclipse and make it show a particular dialog or wizard at startup via command line?
- how do I find out an ID of this wizard to pass to Eclipse?

Here is a screenshot of the wizard that I want to open:

[image]

Comment: There isn't any support for opening wizards from the command line.

Comment: Can you please link the bug you're talking about? With the p2 director, you can install an SVN connector or other plug-ins headless directly from the command line. Scripting the UI, e. g. open a dialog on startup, can be done with Eclipse EASE. Use the plug-in spy to get the ID of a wizard.

Comment: @howlger as far as I recall I was trying to report this bug to subversive-defects@eclipse.org several times but my emails never get through. I've just sent the report again.

Comment: @howlger here you go: https://www.eclipse.org/lists/subversive-defects/msg00048.html :)

Comment: That is the mailing list (you have to subscribe the list to be able to post) and not the bug tracker (and by the way, please describe how to reproduce your issue without using words like _annoying_). Installing multiple connectors makes no sense as only one connector can be used. If you want a different connector, does uninstalling the current connector work?

Comment: @howlger I assumed that the bug has to be reported to the mailing list first. Anyway, I am going to report this to bugzilla, too. Thank you. PS I cannot report this to bugzilla now since I do not remember my password and the https://accounts.eclipse.org/user/password link leads to 404 (You have requested a page or file which does not exist.).

Comment: @howlger BTW, thank you for the idea about removing currently installed SVN connector. It works - the button Get connectors becomes available. The button is required when I was using SVNKit, but have to switch to JavaHL now.

Comment: Maybe https://accounts.eclipse.org/user/password was only temporarily unavailable, please try again. If my answer below doesn't answer your question, please tell what's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the button is **intentionally shown only if no connector is installed** yet. Therefore, **uninstalling the existing connector** (in *Help > About Eclipse IDE* click the *Installation Details* button, in the installation details dialog in the *Installed Software* tab select the connector and click *Uninstall...*) should **display the button again**. If you think another behavior would be better here, you can [report it to Eclipse Subversive](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Subversive).

Alternatively, an SVN connector or other plug-ins can be install headless directly from the command line using the [p2 director](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html).

Scripting the UI, e. g. open a dialog on startup, can be done with [Eclipse EASE](https://www.eclipse.org/ease/). Use the [Eclipse PDE's Plug-in Spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlatformDevelopment/article.html#plug-in-spy-for-ui-parts) to get the ID of a wizard.